# Spring thymeleaf: how to show an alert

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am developing a crud for a project. I would like to show an alert when the administrator edits an employee, product, whatever it is, to show an alert with the message "successfully edited". I can show this message, but I wanted to show it in an alert.

My model:

```
// Edit
@GetMapping("/dashboard/contato/editar/{id}")
public String edit(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model)
{   
    Contato contato = contatoService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("contato", contato);

    return "dashboard/pages/contato/editar";
}

@RequestMapping("/dashboard/contato/editar/{id}")
public String update(@Valid Contato contato, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes,Model model)
{
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "Verifique se os campos 
        obrigatórios foram preenchidos!");
        return "redirect:/dashboard/contato/editar/{id}";
    }else{
        contatoService.save(contato);
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Editado com sucesso!");
        return "redirect:/dashboard/contato";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery's `document ready` function to show alert each time user redirects to your success page. So when each time the page loaded, browser will automatically runs the document ready function ( For more on jquery document ready function refer to the official article - 
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Moreover you can user **thymeleaf + javascript** as well if you want to show alert message based on some dynamic condition. For more details on how to use thymeleaf with javascript , refer this official documentation - 
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining